# Copy files to an SMB share as non-root user

Tags: windows, samba, cifs, smb

I would like to access and copy some files to an SMB share. These commands work with sudo, no username/password is needed:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/share ~/share/ -o rw
cp *pdf share/
umount share/
```

Is there a way to do this as non-root user?

Answer (score 1):

Either you add a mount option

> **mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/share ~/share/ -o rw username=XYXY,password=XYXYXY**

or you write a textfile

> **gedit ~/.smbcredentials**

with the content:

**username=XYXY**

**password=XYXYXY**

After that type

> **sudo chmod 600 ~/.smbcredentials**

Now try mounting:

> **mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/share ~/share/ -o rw credentials=~/.smbcredentials**

For reference: http://forums.buffalotech.com/t5/Storage/Instructions-mount-Linkstation-shares-on-Linux-system-Ubuntu/td-p/63306